# HttpWebRequest get “underlying connection was closed”

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

I would try to grep the response from the login page, but fail as reponse
The error message is just "underlying connection was closed"
Can anyone help me?  This code work before.

```
string urlAddress = "https://signin.apple.com/IDMSWebAuth/signin?path=%2FAU%2Fen_AU%2Freserve%2FiPhone%3Fexecution%3De1s1%26p_left%3DAAAAAARnj9%252FlLm%252F2mQECWTe94HrTcWMnWr9QWWgOrvbtnbiXYw%253D%253D%26_eventId%3Dnext&p_time=1536941435&rv=1&language=AU-EN&p_left=AAAAAARnj9%2FlLm%2F2mQECWTe94HrTcWMnWr9QWWgOrvbtnbiXYw%3D%3D&appIdKey=db0114b11bdc2a139e5adff448a1d7325febef288258f0dc131d6ee9afe63df3";
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(urlAddress);
            request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
        request.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version10;
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";  
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                Stream receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream();
                StreamReader readStream = null;

                if (response.CharacterSet == null)
                {
                    readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream);
                }
                else
                {
                    readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.GetEncoding(response.CharacterSet));
                }

                string data = readStream.ReadToEnd();

                response.Close();
                readStream.Close();

            }
```

Comment: Could be an issue with the network or a firewall. I would suggest attempting to reach the URL in an ordinary browser (running on the same machine as your code) to see if it can go through at all.

Comment: For ie and chrome, it can access it